# Save as PDF Macro, with dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

So I've been using a macro to save sheets as PDF, but now instead of using multiple sheets, I'm using one sheet that pulls all the needed information using a drop down from cell A1 then based on the dropdown's cell value, other fields on the sheet get updated.

The following macro used to go sheet by sheet:

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs()
Dim sFile       As String
Dim sPath       As String
Dim wks         As Worksheet

With ActiveWorkbook
    sPath = .Path & "\"
    For Each wks In .Worksheets
        Select Case wks.Name
            Case Else
                'Code here to run on the other sheets
                sFile = wks.Name & ".pdf"
                wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                        Filename:=sPath & sFile, _
                                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End Select
    Next wks
End With
End Sub
```

Now since I have it all in one sheet, is there a way to go down each item from the drop down for it to populate and automatically save as a PDF? Thanks

Comment: So the code you posted works - you're asking how to run that code for *each item* in the drop down? Say drop down is in `A1` - if you change the value there, other values in the workbook update, correct? And you're wanting to save all the info to a PDF for each option and the resulting data?

Comment: @BruceWayne, yes! Exactly that ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work - You're just going to save the options to an array, then set whatever cell you need to be the option. In my example I used `A1` on the `Sheet1` sheet. Adjust as necessary:

```
Option Explicit

Sub loop_through_dropdown()
     Dim inputRange
     inputRange = Range("A1").Validation.Formula1

     Dim inputs, temp_option As String
     inputs = Split(inputRange, ",")

     Dim i As Long

     For i = LBound(inputs) To UBound(inputs)
        temp_option = (Trim(inputs(i)))
        'do something with temp_option
        Debug.Print (temp_option)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = temp_option
        ' Now, the page should update with the data for that option. Now simply run the macro
        Call SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a Run-Time Error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. When I attempt to debug it, the error appears to be in the SaveAsPDF script. However, before that the value in A1 turns to #VALUE!

Comment: Is the `saveAsPDF` script in the same module as my loop? It should be.  You may need to do `Call SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs()`.  What does the Immediate Window (Press CTRL+G with the VBEditor open) print as the first option?

Comment: Yes, I placed it in the same module. I tried beneath it, Option Explicit would fall under the SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs() after the End, so wouldn't work. Then I tried placing it above the SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs() script, and Option Explicit went on its own section, then I got the same error when I ran it. When I try to pull the Immediate Window I get the range for A1 dropdown, which is ='Sheet1'!$E$5:$E$400

Comment: Just calling the `SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs` macro will not work the SaveAs needs to be rewritten so it is not looking for each worksheet. Also the `FileName:` needs to be changed.

Comment: I was thinking about using a `Worksheet_Change` event for the listbox and adding the `SaveAs` into it. that way the OP could use the listbox to select what data he wants to save to pdf. I would use the listbox value as the `sFile` variable

Comment: So, what changes would I need to include?